# Revert before cleanup?

Tags: git, smartgit

I have been using Aptana to commit all my changes and hadn't open SmartGit for a while. When I did today it prompted me to 'Clean up' my repository

I now can't find any commits from April...

Is there a way to revert back the most recent change?

[image: after view all commits]

The commits in blue were actually commited a while back. I would like to get back to he last red one "$search_col and $search_val = 0...."

Comment: What makes you think that commits have been lost? Open the Log and use Query|Load All Commits there. Do the commits show up now?

Comment: @mstrap ahh thank you sooo much!! I was literally in tears. I'm new to Git that's my excuse! I went to the Log but it wasn't displaying everything and couldn't find them anywhere

Comment: Please answer this question and mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Clean Up hardly can remove commits (unless they are not registered any more in the ref-log files, .git/logs). In your case, the pointer to the *HEAD* commit may have been lost. You can show all commits using SmartGit's Log and invoking *Query|Load All Commits* there. If there is actually a *HEAD* commit without any *ref* assigned, you may use *Branch|Add Branch* to assign a *ref*, thus making it available to standard Git commands again.

Comment: I can view all commits now, i'm trying to revert the HEAD to today but it has some strange blue arrows that seem to be looping(?
) my commits?

Comment: Did you try to add a branch? Can you post some screenshot, e.g. at http://imageshack.us?

Comment: added img to the original question, i think i tried to Re-Base HEAD but it keeps saying 'refname HEAD is ambiguous' and 'rebase failed'

Comment: Looks like something went wrong with the rebase: (1) make sure you have no local changes. (2) scroll to the first (top-most) commit, this should be your most recent one, right? (3) Use Branch|Reset, select Hard here (will revert all local changes in the working tree). Now your HEAD should be fine again (green arrow should be displayed at the most recent commit). (4) Select the "$search_col" commit and use Branch|Rebase HEAD To. This will finally rebase your local commits onto "$search_col" -- which I guess is what you want to do!?

Comment: "test commit" is the most recent. "added logged in.." onwards came from a while back :/ a massive Undo button should be considered in their next release!

Comment: To go back to "$search_col", use Branch|Reset on this commit.